# How does while loop works with string splicing to find out the length of the string?

Tags: string, while-loop

I came across the following code to find the length of a string using string splicing and while loop:

```
    str='xyz'
    counter=0
    while str[counter:]: 

        counter+=1
    print(counter)
```

I am not able to understand how putting str[counter:] as the condition of while loop exactly works. How does the while loop go about to execute this. I am not understanding the logic. Can someone please help me with this
Thanks

Comment: Might be handy to know the programming language

Answer (score 0):

A string is basically an array of character, in your case `str[0] = x` , `str[1] = y`  and `str[2] = z` .

So the while loop is just printing one character of the string each time, print str[0], str[1], str[2] and so on. The `[counter:]` you can understand as to the end of this array, without the `:` will give you an infinite loop.